# R pandas groupby index of the first row in each group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

How do I get the index of first row in each GROUP BY group?

(I know .groupby.first() return the first row in each group, but I don't know how to get their index)

Thanks much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `first`, you could use `head` instead:

```
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.choice(list('ABC'), 50),'values':np.random.randint(0,100,50)})
df.groupby('A').head(1)
```

OUtput:

```
   A  values
0  C      75
1  B      34
4  A      22
```

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, This should work for you, using [`first_valid_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.first_valid_index.html):

```
df.groupby('grouping_variable').apply(lambda x: x.first_valid_index())
```

Example:

```
>>> df
       data group
0 -0.430336     b
1  2.323743     b
2 -0.065441     b
3 -0.894935     b
4  0.529603     b
5 -1.386138     b
6 -1.198493     b
7 -1.025802     a
8  1.151468     b
9 -0.831743     b

>>> df.groupby('group').apply(lambda x: x.first_valid_index())
group
a    7
b    0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can using `drop_duplicates`

```
df.drop_duplicates('A',keep='first')
```